# How can I rotate a text that is in a button?

Tags: android, button, text, rotation

How can I rotate a text that is in a button? For example, to -90 degrees. 
Please I need this for a project.

xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/btnTab"
    android:gravity="bottom"/>
```

Java:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tile_layout,parent,false);
    Button btnTab = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTab);
    Tile temp = objeccts.get(position);
    btnTab.setText(temp.getName());
    return view;
```

so that the button will look like this:

[image]

Comment: @YvetteColomb I added a picture of the requested situation

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can try -

```
view.animate().rotationBy(-90);
```

Comment: The  text remains at the same angle